# Fullcalendar right sidebar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm developing a schedule with fullcalendar React, I know fullcalendar pretty well, but this time I need a right sidebar in front of the resources to display counters by resources, but I can't find anything in the documentation that says it's possible.

Basically, I would like to do like this mockup, on the left the resources, the schedule, plus counters on the right.
[image]

Do you know if this is possible? I am also interested in a package as flexible as fullcalendar with this possibility if it is not possible... Thanks a lot !

Comment: No it's not possible currently (either in v5 or the newer v6). You can put it on the left very easily though, with all the other columns.

Comment: @ADyson Ok thanks, that's what I thought, but I wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything. Thank you.